# How to get last Mitsuku answer as string in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

[Mitsuku](http://www.square-bear.co.uk/mitsuku/nfchat.htm) is chatbot, i need her last answer on my question as string in my visual basic project.
I tried with:

```
Dim PageElements1 As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("font") 
For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElements1
  If CurElement.GetAttribute("color") = "#000000" Then
   Mystring = CurElement.InnerText
  End If
Next
```

and tons of other ways, but i cant even find element with our conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking the owner for permission might be a polite way to start...

If you tell me more about your project, I might be able to help.

Regards
- Steve Worswick
(Mitsuku's developer)

Comment: This is not an answer and should be a comment instead.

Comment: Well hello :) just making facebook chat bot, to troll friends :D

Comment: Sorry guys. I only found out about this through a Google alert and clicked the answer button instead of comment. Also sorry but I don't want you to use Mitsuku to troll people on Facebook. You can make a free bot at www.pandorabots.com without leeching my work.